# Problem adding commons-configuration to m2eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I want to use the apache commons configuration jars in my Maven project.

When I add it using m2Eclipse it produces this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
  <version>20041012.002804</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

This seems fine but it then givers me the error:

> **Missing artifact resources:resources:jar:1.0:compile**

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you need to choose a reliable version. That one seems to be a snapshot build. Here is the excerpt from my project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```